# HR Data Entry Form allows addition of new employees and update of existing employees

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Business Process:** Data entry form allows HR employees to input data for new employees, update data for existing employees, or terminate employees. Three data storage sheets exist for existing employees: Basic information, personal information, and education information, and one exists for separated employee information.

For a new employee, an ID is generated, HR rep manually inputs data into entry form, presses save, and a new row is populated in each of the three existing employee sheets with relevant information.

For an existing employee, HR rep enters the ID; entry form populates with an existing employee's data, HR rep edits, presses "save," and existing rows in the three existing employee sheets update accordingly.

To terminate an employee, the HR rep enters the ID and presses "separate employee." A new row is populated in the separated employee sheet with relevant information and that employee's rows in the other three sheets are deleted.

**Help Requested:** I am relatively new to Google Apps Script and coding in general and have been able to muscle my way through this so far but would like some help with efficiency and code hygiene. Specifically, I'm worried about:

1. I use many of the same variables in the various functions but am re-defining them each time because I'm not sure how to not do this (don't think globally defining would work..)
2. I have a lot of inflexible references (not sure the proper name for this), where I reference ranges with actual cell references (D5:D40), which then have to get updated any time I add a row or column into any of the data or entry sheets.
3. There are probably many other issues that I'm not even aware of and would greatly appreciate any advice.

````
//Function goal: Clear contents of data entry sheet and add age formula
function onOpen(){

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var basicInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Basic Employee Information");
  var personalInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Personal Information");
  var dataEntrySheet = sss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
  dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D40").clearContent();
  dataEntrySheet.getRange("D29").setFormula('iferror(if(D28="","",datedif(D28,today(),"Y")))');
}


//Transpose any array
function transpose(array){

  return Object.keys(array[0]).map(function (c) { return array.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}


//Function goal: Prepare data entry sheet to accept new employee information
function newEmployee() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var basicInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Basic Employee Information");
  var personalInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Personal Information");
  var dataEntrySheet = sss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
  var sepEmpSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Separated Employees");
  var eduSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Education Information");

  //Clear existing data in data entry fields
  dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D40").clearContent();
  dataEntrySheet.getRange("D29").setFormula('iferror(if(D28="","",datedif(D28,today(),"Y")))');

  //Paste next employee ID into data entry sheet
  var basicInfoLastRow = basicInfoSheet.getLastRow();
  var sepEmpLastRow = sepEmpSheet.getLastRow();

  var basicLastID = basicInfoSheet.getRange(basicInfoLastRow,1).getValue();
  var sepLastID = sepEmpSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow,1).getValue();

  dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5").setValue(Math.max(basicLastID,sepLastID)+1);
}


//Function goal: Save data entered in data entry fields to basic employee information, personal information, and education information sheets
function saveData(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var basicInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Basic Employee Information");
  var personalInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Personal Information");
  var dataEntrySheet = sss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
  var eduInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Education Information");
  var lastRow = basicInfoSheet.getLastRow();
  var basicInfoLastCol = basicInfoSheet.getLastColumn();
  var personalInfoLastCol = personalInfoSheet.getLastColumn();
  var eduInfoLastCol = eduInfoSheet.getLastColumn();

  //Enter N/A into empty cells
  var dataRange = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D40");
  var dataRangeFlat = dataRange.getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});

  for(var ct = 0; ct<dataRange.getNumRows(); ct++){
    if(dataEntrySheet.getRange(ct+5,4).isBlank()===true){
      dataEntrySheet.getRange(ct+5,4).setValue("N/A");
    }
      }
  var dataRange = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D40");
  var dataRangeFlat = dataRange.getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0];});

  //If missing data, notify of missing data and confirm the save
  if(dataRangeFlat.indexOf("N/A")>-1){
    var result = ui.alert("Some fields have not been filled in","Would you like to save employee with incomplete data?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if(result === ui.Button.YES){

      //Transpose data to update
      var basicData = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D15").getValues();
      var personalData = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D16:D35").getValues();
      var eduData = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D36:D40").getValues();
      var basicDataT = transpose(basicData);
      var personalDataT = transpose(personalData);
      var eduDataT = transpose(eduData);

      //If employee not already in system, create a new row in each spreadsheet and add the data
      var newID = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
      var existingIDs = basicInfoSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,1).getValues();
      var existingIDsFlat = existingIDs.map(function(row) {return row[0];});
      var name = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
      var position = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D10").getValue();

      if(existingIDsFlat.indexOf(newID)==-1){

        //Add row and data to basic employee information sheet
        basicInfoSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
        basicInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,basicInfoLastCol).setValues(basicDataT);

        //Add row and data to personal information sheet
        personalInfoSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
        personalInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(newID);
        personalInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(name);
        personalInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,3).setValue(position);
        personalInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,4,1,personalInfoLastCol-3).setValues(personalDataT);

        //Add row and data to education information sheet
        eduInfoSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
        eduInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(newID);
        eduInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(name);
        eduInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,3).setValue(position);
        eduInfoSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,4,1,eduInfoLastCol-3).setValues(eduDataT);

        //Notify user that data has been saved
        ui.alert("Complete","New employee information saved",ui.ButtonSet.OK);

      //If an employee already in the system, overwrite existing data
      } else {

        //Notify user that employee is already in the system and ask if they want to proceed
        var result = UI.alert("Employee ID already exists","Do you want to update existing employee information?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

        //If yes - update existing employee
        if(result === ui.Button.YES){
          var targetRow = existingIDsFlat.indexOf(newID)+2;

          basicInfoSheet.getRange(targetRow,1,1,basicInfoLastCol).setValues(basicDataT);
          personalInfoSheet.getRange(targetRow,4,1,personalInfoLastCol-3).setValues(personalDataT);
          eduInfoSheet.getRange(targetRow,4,1,eduInfoLastCol-3).setValues(eduDataT);

          ui.alert("Employee information updated");

        //If no - do not update existing employee, return to the data entry screen and alert that data not updated
        } else {
          ui.alert("Employee information not updated");
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}




//Function goal: Find existing employee data and update via data entry screen
function updateEmployee(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Update employee information","Please enter the employee ID:",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  //Process user's response
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();

  if(button==ui.Button.OK){
    var employeeID = Number(text)

    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var basicInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Basic Employee Information");
    var personalInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Personal Information");
    var eduInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Education Information")
    var dataEntrySheet = sss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
    var lastRow = basicInfoSheet.getLastRow();
    var basicInfoLastCol = basicInfoSheet.getLastColumn();
    var personalInfoLastCol = personalInfoSheet.getLastColumn();
    var eduInfoLastCol = eduInfoSheet.getLastColumn();

    var existingIDs = basicInfoSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,1).getValues();
    var existingIDsFlat = existingIDs.map(function(row) {return row[0];});

    //If employee ID does not exist, prompt for new ID
    if(existingIDsFlat.indexOf(employeeID)==-1){
      ui.alert("Employee ID does not exist, please try again.",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    }

    else {
      //If employee ID does exist, clear data entry contents and replace with employee data
      dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D40").clearContent();

      var targetRow = existingIDsFlat.indexOf(employeeID)+2;
      var basicData = basicInfoSheet.getRange(targetRow,1,1,basicInfoLastCol).getValues();
      var personalData = personalInfoSheet.getRange(targetRow,4,1,personalInfoLastCol-3).getValues();
      var eduData = eduInfoSheet.getRange(targetRow,4,1,eduInfoLastCol-3).getValues();

      var basicDataT = transpose(basicData);
      var personalDataT = transpose(personalData);
      var eduDataT = transpose(eduData);

      dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5:D15").setValues(basicDataT);
      dataEntrySheet.getRange("D16:D35").setValues(personalDataT);
      dataEntrySheet.getRange("D36:D40").setValues(eduDataT);

      //Replace age equation
      dataEntrySheet.getRange("D29").setFormula('iferror(if(D28="","",datedif(D28,today(),"Y")),"N/A")');
    }
  }
}



//Function goal: Separate employee - add employee information to separated employee sheet and remove the employee from other sheets
function removeEmployee(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please confirm","If you are sure you want to separate employee, please enter separation date",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Process user's response
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();

  //If separation date entered, continue
  if(text!=""){
    var basicInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Basic Employee Information");
    var dataEntrySheet = sss.getSheetByName("Data Entry");
    var personalInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Personal Information");
    var eduInfoSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Education Information");
    var separatedSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Separated Employees");
    var basicInfoLastRow = basicInfoSheet.getLastRow();
    var sepEmpLastRow = separatedSheet.getLastRow();

    var existingIDs = basicInfoSheet.getRange(2,1,basicInfoLastRow-1,1).getValues();
    var existingIDsFlat = existingIDs.map(function(row) {return row[0];});

    var employeeID = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
    var name = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
    var position = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D10").getValue();
    var startDate = dataEntrySheet.getRange("D7").getValue();
    var sepDate = text

    var sourceRow = existingIDsFlat.indexOf(employeeID)+2;
    var targetRow = sepEmpLastRow+1;

    //Add row to separated sheet with relevant values
    separatedSheet.insertRowAfter(sepEmpLastRow);
    separatedSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow+1,1).setValue(employeeID);
    separatedSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow+1,2).setValue(name);
    separatedSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow+1,3).setValue(position);
    separatedSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow+1,4).setValue(startDate);
    separatedSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow+1,5).setValue(sepDate);

    //Copy length of employment calculation down
    separatedSheet.getRange(sepEmpLastRow,6).copyTo(separatedSheet.getRange(targetRow,6), {contentsOnly:false});

    //Remove row from basic employee information and personal information sheets
    basicInfoSheet.deleteRow(sourceRow);
    personalInfoSheet.deleteRow(sourceRow);
    eduInfoSheet.deleteRow(sourceRow);

  //If separation date not entered, do nothing  
  }
}
```
````